# Shopify select The Radio Buttons Of The First Available Variant By Default

Tags: javascript, radio-button, shopify, liquid, variant

I am developing a theme from scratch and I am facing a problem where I am rendering the product options as radio button groups. When the user selects or changes the radio button, I am updating the price accordingly. My problem is, I don't know how to select the first available variant as the selected radio button values. The way I am doing it, it's making the last available variant as the default selected radio buttons when the page loads.

Any help will be much appreciated. Here is my code:

```
<!-- storing the variants in json form -->
<script id="variants" type="application/json">
    {{ product.variants | json }}
</script>

<!-- creating an array from the json data-->
<script>
    var variantsArray= JSON.parse(document.getElementById("variants").text);
    console.log(variantsArray);
</script>
<span class="unit-price">{{ price | money }}</span>
          <!-- rendering the radio button groups -->
                <div class="radios">

                    {% for product_option in product.options_with_values %} 
                        <h4 class="options-title">{{ product_option.name }}</h4>
                        <div class="options-values">
                            {% for value in product_option.values %}
                                <input type="radio" id = "{{ value }}" name="{{ product_option.name}}" value="{{ value }}" checked >
                                <label for="{{ value }}">{{ value }}</label>  
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                       <div class="line"></div>
                  {% endfor %}

                  <!-- script for updating the price on variant change -->
                  <script>
                    var radioArray = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
                    var checkedArray = [];
                    for (let k=0; k<radioArray.length; k++) {
                        radioArray[k].addEventListener('change', function () {
                            var checkedValues = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked');
                            checkedArray = Array.from(checkedValues, radio => radio.value);
                            console.log(checkedArray);
                            
                            for (let l=0; l < variantsArray.length; l++) {
                                //if the variant selection matches the json variant options then update the price
                                if ((JSON.stringify(checkedArray))== (JSON.stringify(variantsArray[l].options))) {
                                    //formatting the price manually (need to fix later)
                                    var priceString = variantsArray[l].price.toString();
                                    document.querySelector('.unit-price').textContent = `$${priceString.substr(0,priceString.length-2)}`;
                                }
                            }

                        })  
                    }  
                 </script>

                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add an if condition inside the radio button.

```
{% for value in product_option.values %}
    <input type="radio" id = "{{ value }}" name="{{ product_option.name}}" 
    value="{{ value }}" {% if forloop.index == 1 %} checked="checked" {% endif %}>
    <label for="{{ value }}">{{ value }}</label>  
{% endfor %}
```